# Can you view data being sent and received from a windows third party application

Tags: resources, monitor

I want to view the raw data being received from a downloaded application.
When i check resource monitor (network tab) i can see the relevant application .exe running and can see bytes recieve per minute but how can i view raw data?
If i were to do the same on a website i would go into the network tab of inspect and preview the raw data.

Comment: Have you tried with wireshark?

Comment: I have tried wireshark, there was a lot of noise. The packets in wireshark are encrypted too? Is there a way to use wireshark to get the relevant data?